# Symfony forms: Save form containing checkboxes and/or choice widgets?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I have a Doctrine table that contains the following fields:

```
Article:
  columns:
    title:
      type: string(40)
    content:
      type: string(255)
    publish:
      type: boolean
```

I am creating a custom form for creating Articles on my site. In my custom form I have a checkbox for the `publish` field. When submitting the form, if the checkbox is checked, the form value for it comes back as "on". If the checkbox is NOT checked, the form value is non-existent.

Because I'm working with a form that extends Doctrine's Model Forms, I'd like to be able to simply do a `$this->form->save();` when it passes validity.

But if the checkbox for `publish` only gives the value of `on` or nothing, then neither value is valid for the database. The form saves properly but the database value for `publish` is always just default no matter if the checkbox is checked or not.

What is the correct approach to this problem?

Also, how do you deal with choice sfWidgets? The passed values is an array of values. `$this->form-save()` seems to ignore those arrays.

Do you manually have to get the values from the form and create a Doctrine Collection from the values and save it that way? Or is there a better method that Symfony expects you to use?

Answer (score 0):

Is your validator for publish an instance of `sfValidatorBoolean`? If it is, it should return false.

Your question about choice widgets requires more elaboration. Please paste your form's `configure` method, the values you are receiving from `$form->getValues()`, and what you expect to be receiving.

Comment: I will paste in some stuff tomorrow. Are you supposed to set a validator for checkboxes?  It's either going to be checked or not checked. How could it be anything different? What is there to validate?